# SDL streaming audio C++

Tags: c++, sdl, audio-streaming

So I'm very new to C++, and recently I learn how to use libraries, I have a project in python that uses PyAudio for streaming audio and getting from that audio a 1D array. I'm trying to do that same project but on C++, the problem is that the C++ documentation are very confusing to me, for example, I'm using SDL_audio library for Audio Streaming, but I can't manage to use it propertly. here are the docs I'm trying to follow https://wiki.libsdl.org/Tutorials-AudioStream I don't understand very well, how can I stream audio in a while loop with the code the docs give me?

Right now I only have this code, but I really don't know what is this or how to implement Audio streaming with c++ and SDL_audio:/

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL_audio.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {

    SDL_AudioStream *stream = SDL_NewAudioStream(AUDIO_S16, 1, 22050, AUDIO_F32, 2, 48000);

    if (stream == NULL) {
        printf("Uhoh, stream failed to create: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else {
    
    }



}
```

any help:)

Comment: What does "streaming audio" mean? Playing audio? In any case, the first thing you need to do is `SDL_Init` to initialize SDL.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no, streaming audio means like, reading the microphone input in real-time

Comment: Surely this word has more than one meaning, because `SDL_NewAudioStream` is used to convert between different audio formats. Recording audio is done using `SDL_OpenAudioDevice` and related functions. Dno't forget to `SDL_Init` first.